# Spring Boot Microservices Monitoring & Management

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper, spring-boot-admin

We are planning to build a micro services based, distributed architecture for our application. We have done PoCs on several concepts too. But I am bit confused about the various management and monitoring solutions which Spring Boot offers. I would appreciate if you can clarify my queries below:

- Spring Boot Admin can manage and monitor several micro services (I have tried out this too). I also hear about Spring cloud dashboard (I haven't tried, but trying to understand it conceptually). While I understand that Spring cloud features generally include enterprise level features, I am confused between what is the difference between Spring Boot Admin and Spring Cloud Dashboard.
- I understand that Spring Boot Admin server can monitor any Spring boot based micro service, provided we add the correct dependency and configure it correctly. Now suppose I have a long running batch process and for whatever reason, the application is not responding (say, in the middle of processing a file). Is there any way Spring Boot admin server can notify such an issue? Yes, assume that I have added necessary dependencies and configured the service correctly for Spring boot admin client (Though the main application might be processing files from an SFTP server and updating a database in batch mode)
- If we package each service into containers (for example as docker images), I think we will be able to monitor each service using Spring Boot Admin. But is there a better way to monitor and manage services in Docker platform? I have done some research and found that if we are deploying it into a cloud platform such as AWS or Azure, we can rely on the cloud provider's features to monitor each container rather than our solution. Is this true?
- Is it possible to monitor custom events / statistics using Spring Boot Admin rather than the out of the box parameters? For example, I would like to know the number of records in each file and the ones got successfully processed. Can I send these kind of information to Spring Boot Admin Server so that I can view them in Spring Boot Admin UI?
- I understand that Zookeeper is a good alternative to discovery service, but some folks are saying that we can use that also for monitoring and managing micro services. Is it true and is it a popular among the community?

Sorry for the long post, but I thought I will ask everything related in one post. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring Boot Admin is only fancy tool, nice during development phase, but not suited to be used in production.
2. microservices-dashboard-server doesn't seem to work https://github.com/ordina-jworks/microservices-dashboard . I'v tried also newest snapshot
3. Hystrix + Turbine seems interesting but last commit was few years ago

Generally infrastructure replace many of such solutions. Good thing is you don't need to support it yourself. Bad thing is you're tied to cloud provider.